# Zencoder api is working in local but not in Live

Tags: php, api, zencoder

I am using Zencoder API for video conversion. I have generated two different API keys for my local and live server.

When I am testing the conversion of video from my local its sending request to Zencoder and working fine. But, when same process I am doing with my live server then its not sending any request to Zencoder API. Using, FTP for sending request and reponse.

My input and output URL generating like

```
define('INPUT_URL', "ftp://username:password@127.0.0.1/project/upload/");
define('OUTPUT_URL', "ftp://username:password@127.0.0.1/project/upload/");    
$inputUrl = INPUT_URL.$fileInfo['file_name'] . '.' . $fileInfo['file_type'];
$outputUrl = OUTPUT_URL.$new_file;
```

127.0.0.1 written as per example. In my code using my live IP.

Any idea why it may not be working in live?
Thank!

Comment: are you sure ftp is enabled and you are providing correct credentials on live site?

Comment: Yes, I am giving correct credentials for live site. As, am using ftp for live site.

Comment: @BiswajitMaji: Am getting error as 'Peer Certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA Certificates'